# Intended footnote with mark * while using command deffootnote

Tags: footnotes, koma-script, indentation

I have used the package scrextend with document class article to delete the indent in footnotes using the command deffootnote. But there is a footnote within the author name (with the footnotemark *) which remains indented. How can I remove the Indent from this first footnote with the footnotemark *

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}


\deffootnote[0em]{0em}{0em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\,}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\title{\large Rezension/Review \\
Grün, Anselm und Ahmad Milad Karimi. \textit{Im Herzen der Spiritualität: Wie sich Muslime und Christen begegnen können.} Herausgegeben von Rudolf Walter. 1. Auflage. Freiburg Basel Wien: Verlag Herder 2019, 288 Seiten}
\author{\hspace{-8.0cm}\textit{Muhammed Ragab}\footnote{Muhammed Ragab M.A. ist wissenschaftlicher Mitarbeiter am Department für Islamisch-Religiöse Studien DIRS der FAU Erlangen-Nürnberg. Er promiviert zurzeit dort zum Thema „Von Kritik zum Aufbau: Diskurs der Tradition und Erneuerung in Ägypten“}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\noindent Begegnungen zwischen Muslimen und Christen können bis zu der frühen Entstehungszeit des Islam datiert werden. Friedlich sind sie begonnen mit Ereignissen wie der (fragwürdigen) Geschichte vom Treffen zwischen dem Propheten und dem Mönch \textit{Baḥīra}\footnote{Vgl. Muḥammad Ibn-Isḥāq: \textit{Das Leben des Propheten.} Übers. von Gernot Rotter. 4. Aufl, Dali/Nikosia, Zypern: Spohr 2008, S. 36–38.} vor der Botschaft  und der christlichen Delegation von \textit{Naǧrān}\footnote{Vgl. ebd., S. 120.} nach der Botschaft.  Im Laufe der Zeit schwankten die Begegnungen zwischen Frieden und Gewalt bis zu unserer heutigen Zeit, wobei in Europa die Muslime 4.9\% der Bevölkerung und in Deutschland 6.1\% bilden.  
\end{document}
```

And here is the result
[image: The result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KOMA-Script command `\deffootnote` redefines `\@makefnmark`.

If option `titlepage` is not set for class `article`, `maketitle` redefines `\@makefnmark` locally. So the settings by `\deffootnote` does not affect such an article title.

Workaround: you could patch `\@maketitle` to restore your settings for the footnote

```latex
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\if@titlepage\else
  \xpretocmd{\@maketitle}
    {\deffootnote[0em]{0em}{0em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\,}}
    {}{\PatchFailed}
  \fi
\makeatother
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\deffootnote[0em]{0em}{0em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\,}
\makeatletter
\if@titlepage\else
  \xpretocmd{\@maketitle}
    {\deffootnote[0em]{0em}{0em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\,}}
    {}{\PatchFailed}
  \fi
\makeatother

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% needed with older TeX distrubtions
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}% <- changed
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\title{\large Rezension/Review \\
Grün, Anselm und Ahmad Milad Karimi. \textit{Im Herzen der Spiritualität: Wie sich Muslime und Christen begegnen können.} Herausgegeben von Rudolf Walter. 1. Auflage. Freiburg Basel Wien: Verlag Herder 2019, 288 Seiten}
\author{\hspace{-8.0cm}\textit{Muhammed Ragab}\footnote{Muhammed Ragab M.A. ist wissenschaftlicher Mitarbeiter am Department für Islamisch-Religiöse Studien DIRS der FAU Erlangen-Nürnberg. Er promiviert zurzeit dort zum Thema „Von Kritik zum Aufbau: Diskurs der Tradition und Erneuerung in Ägypten“}}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\noindent Begegnungen zwischen Muslimen und Christen können bis zu der frühen Entstehungszeit des Islam datiert werden. Friedlich sind sie begonnen mit Ereignissen wie der (fragwürdigen) Geschichte vom Treffen zwischen dem Propheten und dem Mönch \textit{Bahīra}\footnote{Vgl. Muhammad Ibn-Ishāq: \textit{Das Leben des Propheten.} Übers. von Gernot Rotter. 4. Aufl, Dali/Nikosia, Zypern: Spohr 2008, S. 36–38.} vor der Botschaft  und der christlichen Delegation von \textit{Naǧrān}\footnote{Vgl. ebd., S. 120.} nach der Botschaft.  Im Laufe der Zeit schwankten die Begegnungen zwischen Frieden und Gewalt bis zu unserer heutigen Zeit, wobei in Europa die Muslime 4.9\% der Bevölkerung und in Deutschland 6.1\% bilden.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This method worked within this article,
I have tried to use with a more complicated article with more packages, where also the footmisc package didn't also work to unindent the footnotes